# Origin of the term "planar graph"

Tags: general-topology, graph-theory, math-history

I would like to know who coined the term **planar graph**?

I was able to trace the term back to a paper "Non-Separable and Planar Graphs" by Hassler Whitney, Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci USA. 1931 February; 17(2): 125–127.  Is this the first occurrence?

Obviously, planar graphs have been studied as 1-skeletons of polyhedral genus-0 surfaces before (Euler-Poincare formula), but not under this name.

**Addition:**
Thanks to the pointer of Hagen v. Eitzen I found that in the Bulletin of the AMS 1930, pg 214 the following abstract was listed.

> **Professors Orrin Frink and P.A.Smith:**
>
> *Irreducible non-planar graphs.*
> One of the results of this paper is a simple necessary and sufficient condition that an arbitrary linear graph be mappable on a plane.
> (Received February 10,1930.)

The paper was sent out for publication in Trans. of the ACM, but since Kuratowski's result came out just a few months earlier (and it had a similar proof) it got rejected. So this is the first appearance of the term "non-planar graph" I could found.

By the way, Kuratowski's article was in French, and from my understanding there is no direct analogue for "planar graphs" in the text.

Comment: The term *plane graph* is also used.

Comment: @lhf Though that is a slightly different concept, I think (a graph embedded in a plane vs. a graph embeddable in a plane)

Answer (score 2):

I suppose some hints can be found in
N. L. Biggs, E. K. Lloyd and R. J. Wilson,
*Graph Theory 1736-1936* (1976) though I don't have access to that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. This is a cool book. It helped me a bit further (see additional remarks in the question), but I do not a have a definite answer yet.